Blocked alias domain name on vpn(s) (zscaler, OpenVPN) but not CNAME
We own a domain name on Namecheap (we used it for a about a year now) to which we recently added a CNAME record (2 weeks ago). It seems to be working fine since when we visit the Namecheap URL (maindomain.com), it points to the website added as the CNAME (maindomain.cms-brand.com). Now, the only issue is that VPNs seem to block access to the main domain (maindomain.com). The VPNs we tested on are ZScaler and OpenVPN. However, we can access the subdomain (maindomain.cms-brand.com) without issue.
For more details, here are the errors we get on both vpns:

OpenVPN the french part says this website can't provide a secure connexion.

ZScaler.


Also, we're not the ones using these VPNs so we have no admin access to the vpn configuration or anything similar.
I thought the issue was categorization or lack of meta tags, but I added all of those, and nothing changed. Does anyone have an idea about what could be causing this?
Thanks in advance.
